# OpenCV init done, opengl support available

Tags: opencv

I am writing a Frame server program on python that receives frame information from a java client. It's actually an android code on a phone that streams the camera frames to the python server.

The python server then handles the frame thanks to opencv that should normally show a window with a Grayscale  representation of what the phone camera is seeing.

So it goes
phone camera => java-android code on phone(uses java sockets) => python socket receiver => opencv window show what camera is seeing.

However, this doesn't show any opencv window and returns `init done opengl support available`.

My frame are 176x144 (total number of pixels is 25344).These pixels are being sent from Java to python.

My java sockets send this information on the same thread as the (android) UI thread I should have implemented async code for this but I'm a noob.

I suspect that  performance might be an issue here but I am not sure what to do since there is no apparent error.

However, I would really like a way to see what the camera is seeing from the opencv window.

My code is below. Thank you for your help.

```cpp
import socket
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from struct import unpack

def showImage(windowName,array):
    cv2.imshow(windowName,array)

def server(host,port):
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)
    c,addr=s.accept()
    while(1):    
        data=c.recv(4)
        width=unpack('>I', data[0:4])[0]
        data2=c.recv(4)
        height=unpack('>I', data2[0:4])[0]
        totalpixels=width*height
        data3=recvall(c,totalpixels)
        frame=np.fromstring(data3,dtype=np.uint8)   
        frame=frame.reshape(height,width)
        cv2.setUseOptimized(True)
        cv2.namedWindow("Driver", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("Driver",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



    return data
def recvall(sock,n):
    data=''
    while len(data)<n:
        chunk=sock.recv(n-len(data))
        if not chunk:
            return None
        data+=chunk

    return data


if __name__=="__main__":
        server('localhost',9999)
```

Comment: put `if (cv2.waitKey(1)&0xff) == 27: break` after the imshow, else nothing ever gets drawn (no messages to do that are passed)